# how to connect Kong prometheus plugin to Grafana using docker?

Tags: prometheus, grafana, kong, kong-plugin, konga

I'm using Kong with KONGA as GUI and added Prometheus plugin for monitoring, however when I try to add the data source to Grafana using Kong endpoint `http://host.docker.internal:8001/metrics`
I always get the below error

Error reading Prometheus: client_error: client error: 404.

How can I connect Grafana data source to localhost:8001/metrics?

Answer (score 1):

Ok, you have one missing piece in your architecture. You need to add `Prometheus` as well which will scrape the metrics from `Kong`. This is the architecture you should have:

> `Kong metrics (8001/metrics)` -> `Prometheus (9090)` -> `Grafana`

The metrics from `Kong` will be ingested by `Prometheus` from time to time and used to create a series database of the metrics obtained.

You will then add `Prometheus` as a data source in `Grafana` which will then make all the metrics collected by `Prometheus` available to `Grafana` for viewing in a dashboard. [Here](https://grafana.com/grafana/dashboards/7424) is the official dashboard for `Kong`.